# Replace words in a list with words in another list that share some letters

Tags: shell, awk, sed, replace, grep

I have a very long list of words (with duplications) like this:

**list1.txt**

```
Apple
Pear
Banana
Banana
Banana
Banana
Orange
Orange
```

I want to replace every words in the list1.txt with another list of words (with no duplications), list2.txt, that contains the same words of the list1.txt plus something more:

**list2.txt**

```
Apple_red
Pear_green
Banana_yellow
Orange_orange
```

I need an output like this:

**list3.txt**

```
Apple_red
Pear_green
Banana_yellow
Banana_yellow
Banana_yellow
Banana_yellow
Orange_orange
Orange_orange
```

Any suggestions? **Thank you!**

Comment: Please wrap your samples in code tags.

Comment: What if a word appears in list1 that isn't represented in list2? Wouldn't you at least want some kind of warning about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk -F'_' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} {print a[$1]}' list2.txt list1.txt
```

```
Apple_red
Pear_green
Banana_yellow
Banana_yellow
Banana_yellow
Banana_yellow
Orange_orange
Orange_orange
```

Comment: or slightly briefer `awk -F'_' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next} {print a[$0]}'`.  I wonder what the OP would want to happen if a word from list1 didn't appear in list2 though...

Comment: oh yes that is certainly shorter , thanks so much Ed

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
uniq list1.txt | paste -d/ - list2.txt | sed 's#.*#s/&/#' | sed -f - list1.txt
```

- Remove duplicates from list1.txt
- Join list1.txt and list2.txt using a `/` as separator.
- Create a sed substitution script from result of above.
- Apply the sed script to list1.txt original file